# Windows server 2012 IIS hosted application on same port can not access from server itself

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

I have hosted several web applications on same port in IIS server on windows server 2012. 
When I tried to access those by using domain names via browser from server itself, nothing is loading. 
Can any one help me on this ?

Edited :

This is how I have set up bindings.

[image]

Comment: Go to iis and select your application then select file from content view and then try to browse, try and if then also error occur then let me know.

Comment: Have you change binding setting of your application

Comment: When I brows from IIS it opens the browser with domain name we've configured but it continues loading and show nothing. Yes I've changed the binding for every websites. But I can not see any binding settings any where.

Comment: if you are able show the screenshot then it will be better to resolve

Comment: @yatinparab Please check the edited question. Thank You.

Comment: it is opening from outside, i am able to access the same from my machine,i.e http://justbooksalon.in/.

Comment: Yes, from outside it's working as expected. I need to load it from inside for setup Phantomjs for SEO purpose.

Comment: in binding try to set ip address as all assigned, hope it will resolve.

Comment: if it works from the outside and is failing from the inside then your internal DNS servers need to be able to resolve that name to your 10.x addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an external vs internal resolution issue - Could you temporarily add:

```
10.1.100.190 justbooksalon.in
10.1.100.190 justbooksalon.com
10.1.100.190 justbooksalon.sg
10.1.100.190 www.justbooksalon.in
10.1.100.190 www.justbooksalon.com
10.1.100.190 www.justbooksalon.sg
```

to the server's `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`  file and see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Website justbooksalon.in is rendering from webserver IP address 67.213.65.248 so your webserver should have this IP address on it's network adapter and also on IIS website bindings.
[image]

Your given screen-capture shows private IP address 10.x.x.x instead public IP address 67.213.65.248. Changing binding to 67.213.65.248 should fix the accessibility from inside.

Comment: Depends on if this server is directly connected to outside or if there is a router doing port forwarding sitting between it and the internet.  If the later then they need to look at the router config.